# Append a list of values with mixed types in Python to data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-processing

I have a data frame reading from csv using pandas.read_csv, each row of data frame looks like this:

```
[1, '10/18/2016 06:00', 1, 14, 0, 5.5]
```

Basically, it consists of integers, string, and floats. Now, I want to generate more data (newrow) based on existing data and append to the original data frame. When I try to call function `append` with the following code:

```
df.append(list(newrow))
```

I got the error:

```
RuntimeWarning: unorderable types: str() < int(), sort order is undefined for incomparable objects. 
result = result.union(other)
```

I think the string type is playing naughty here, but I did not figure out a way to achieve this.

In addition, I also tried to convert the `df` to `df.values` first, and then use `numpy.vstack(df.values, numpy.array(newrow))`. However, the result of this code becomes

```
['1', '10/18/2016 06:00', '1', '14', '0', '5.5']
```

in which all fields become strings. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you give a short example of your df and newrow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this work?

```
#build a DataFrame first using the list and column names from original DF.
df.append(pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns,data=[newrow]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, this works! So how does this differ from `df.append(list())` in my code? Why there is an error there but not here?

Comment: df.append only takes DataFrame, Series/dict-like object. To directly append a list will fail because of this. This solution builds a DataFrame first using the list and column names from original df, that's why it works.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work to append to an empty Dataframes. The **columns must match**.

```
column_titles = ['col1','col2']
data = ['1', '10/18/2016 06:00', '1', '14', '0', '5.5']

# creates empty df w/headers
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_titles)

df2 = pd.DataFrame([data])

df = df.append(df2)
```